# QDir absolutePath still returning the filename

Tags: qt, qfiledialog, qdir

```
QString FilePath2 = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Directory"), "C:/", tr("Text files (*.txt)"));
QDir a = FilePath2;
qDebug() << a.absolutePath();
```

Code works fine. But absolutePath() is still returning the path + filename instead of only path.

C:/Users/Blastcore/Desktop/text.txt instead of only C:/Users/Blastcore/Desktop

Any idea?

Comment: Try with `QFileInfo` instead of `QDir`
[http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfileinfo.html#absolutePath]

Comment: Counterintuitively, `QDir` **can** hold a path to a file. If you need to select a directory, not a file, you should use `getExistingDirectory()` instead of `getOpenFileName()`. If you just need the dir in that particular place, use `QFileInfo` as Kirween suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `QFileInfo` instead of `QDir`. With your Example:

```
QString FilePath2 = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Directory"), "C:/", tr("Text files (*.txt)"));
QFileInfo a(FilePath2);
qDebug() << a.absolutePath();
```